# useState updating for all list elements

Tags: reactjs, use-state

[Before Clicking on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FehvQ.png)

[After clicking on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5oVp.png)

So I used useState to play with margins and make a description slide down div which initially hides behind the image itself. I am using map() to diplay a list of images with the same properties. But the useState works fine when using a single image. For multiple images clicking o 1 image activates the slidedown div for all the images. I want them to be seperate. Is there any solution to this?

```
import React,{useState}  from 'react'
import Image1 from '../../images/background1.jpg'
import Image2 from '../../images/background2.jpg'
import {Arts,ArtHeading,CardContainer, Card,CardImg1,CardDetails,CardText} from './ArtsElements';

const images = [
    { title:"Title1", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title2", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title3", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title4", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title5", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title6", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title7", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title8", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title9", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title10", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title11", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title12", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title13", src:Image1},
    { title:"Title14", src:Image1},
];

const Artworks = () => {
    const [isOpen,setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const toggle = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }
    return (
        <Arts >
            <ArtHeading>
                Artworks
            </ArtHeading>
        <CardContainer>
        {
        images.map((img,index) => (
            
                
                    
                <Card >
                    
                    {/* <CardImg1 key={index} src={img.src}   /> */}
                    <CardImg1  src={Image1}  onClick={toggle} />
                    <CardDetails isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggle} >
                                <CardText >
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 
                                 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                 title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4title 4
                                </CardText>
                    </CardDetails>
                    
                    
                </Card>
           
              
            
        ))} 
            
            </CardContainer>
            </Arts>
    )
}

export default Artworks
```

styled components file:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'


export const Arts = styled.div`
background-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 150px;
@media screen and  (max-width:768px){
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
@media screen and  (max-width:480px){
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
`
export const ArtHeading = styled.h1`
font-size: 50px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
@media screen and  (max-width:768px){
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
@media screen and  (max-width:480px){
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

`

export const CardContainer = styled.section`
margin: 50px auto;
width: 90%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
grid-gap: 20px;




`

export const Card = styled.div`


position: relative;
height: 430px;
width:350px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0,0,0,0.5); 

`



export const CardImg1 = styled.img`

width: 100%;
height:100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 10px;

`

export const CardText = styled.p`

`

export const CardDetails = styled.div`
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top:${({isOpen}) => (isOpen ? '40px' : '440px')};
transition: 1s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for opening all is you are setting only true or false for toggle.But you are not telling react which one to toggle.So you can use index as key to compare which one is clicked.
First change

```
<CardImg1  src={Image1}  onClick={()=>toggle(index)} />
<CardDetails isOpen={(isOpen==index)?true:false} onClick={()=>toggle(index)} >
```

then method

```
const toggle = (index) => {
    
        setIsOpen(index)
        
}
```

then use state

```
  const [isOpen,setIsOpen] = useState(null);
```

**Updated:**

```
const toggle = (index) => {
        (isOpen==index)? setIsOpen(-1): setIsOpen(index);
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: what is currentCard?     Error:'currentCard' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: updated my ansewr it should be isOpen. i was trying to use other logic later on used same one which you used

Comment: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
▶ 26 stack frames were collapsed.

This error pops up

Comment: Ya it works fine but clicking on the picture dosent make the slide down go back up. Clicking on another picture does that. Is there any way that the slide down will also go up when clicked on the same picture as well?

Comment: you mean to say.you need to close card details if its clicked even though its opened right

Comment: updated my answer.let me know if its working as expected.if not i have understood it wrongly

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot man. Now i will surely try to understand it..but one last favor if u dont mind.... as you can see..in the picture. I have many images and the details of the upper section images is covered by the below images.What do u think i can change so taht when the details pops down the gap between that image and the lower image increases to give space to the details.

Comment: @KrishnangshukPaul.I am not expert  about css and styling.even i am a beginner at reactjs .you can open new question for that so some one can help you to solve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * You have to distinguish one image from thes rest
 * Currently, you are using one `open` state for all of the images
 *
 */

const [images, setImages] = useState([
  { title: 'Title1', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title2', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title3', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title4', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title5', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title6', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title7', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title8', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title9', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title10', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title11', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title12', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title13', src: Image1, open: false },
  { title: 'Title14', src: Image1, open: false },
]);

// The you toggle function be like this:

const toggle = e => {
  // Find image that was clicked
  const currentImage = images.find(image => (image.title = e.target.name));
  setImages(prevState => [
    // All Images in the previos image
    ...prevState,
    // get all the properties of cuurent image object, and set the open to opposite to what it was before
    { ...currentImage, open: !currentImage.open },
  ]);
};

// Then use map like this:
{
  images.map((img, index) => (
    <Card>
      <CardImg1 src={Image1} onClick={toggle} />
      <CardDetails
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClick={toggle}
        // THis name prop will be used to find the current image
        name={img.title}
      >
        ....
        ....
      </CardDetails>
    </Card>
  ));
}


// maybe to need to change this a bit according your your scenario, but this is the gist of it
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
This Line
{ ...currentImage, open: !currentImage.open },

Comment: You need to check what is in `e.target` Whether you are using onClick on right element

Answer (score 0):

You are having the toggle state in a component which is responsible for rendering the list of images . One downside of this approach is if you have 10 cards and want to toggle the first card you are re-rendering the entire cards list because of the change in state .

The advantage of using react is to build components which are isolated from each other so that we can have a minimal render when the state of the component changes.

You should be moving the toggle state inside the `CardDetails` component. In that way its not required for you to keep track of the index anymore because now each `CardDetails` component will have its own toggle state . And also from now
if you are toggling card - 1 it will only re-render it and not the other cards.

If you have the react dev tools in your browser ( if not please install it as it will help you in debugging ) enable this `Highlight updates when components render` and compare the re-rendering with your current approach and the approach which i suggested .